# Submit form - wait until animation has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, animation

I have a login and on submit on `<div>` should `fadeOut()` and another `fadeIn()`, but it doesn't wait for the animation to finish.

Here's my code:

**JavaScript:**

```
function xSubmit(){
  $('#login').fadeOut(800);
  $('#logo').fadeIn(1500);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id='logo' style="display: none;">
  <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}pics/pic.png">
</div>
<div id='login'>
  <form method="post" id='loginForm' action="{{ action_url }}" autocomplete="off">
   <table>
      <tr>
      </tr>
        <th>Benutzer:</th>
        <td><input type="text" id="username" name="username"></td>
      <tr>
        <th>Passwort:</th>
        <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password"><td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="xSubmit();"></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: And btw you html is not valid ... `td`/`th` is out of `tr`, ...

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell jQuery one is finished start the other one, like this:

The Form:

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" id="btnSubmit">
```

The Action (remove the function xSubmit(){ and just add this:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#login').fadeOut(800, function() {
        $('#logo').fadeIn(1500, function(){
            $('#loginForm').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Is jQuery library Loaded? Try also adding "$(document).ready(function(){" before and "}" after the code

Comment: @user2457241 What goes wrong? This will fade the elements one after another, but does nothing to handle the form submission.

Answer (score 1):

You can you jQuery .promise() method that will wait until animation finishes then do your submit.

```
xSubmit(){
    $('#login').fadeOut(800).promise().done(function(){
      $("#loginForm").submit();
    });
    return false;
}
```

Or use callback on fadeOut method:

```
xSubmit(){
  $('#login').fadeOut(800, function(){
       $("#loginForm").submit();
  })
  return false;
}
```

Edit:
You can prevent form submition by returning false from your function

Also you have option to event parameter to function on your input

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="xSubmit(event);"/>
```

and prevent submition by calling `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: I have tryed: function xSubmit(){
    $('#login').fadeOut(800);
    $('#logo').fadeIn(1500).promise().done(function(){
        $('#loginForm').submit();
    })
}
but dont work..

Comment: @user2457241 What goes wrong? My guess is that the form submits before jQuery does it's thing. You'll need to prevent that so that jQuery can submit the form when it's ready.

Comment: Yeah, I think showdev absolutely right. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass other animation as callback of the 1st one like this:

```
function xSubmit(){
    $('#login').fadeOut(800, function() {
        $('#logo').fadeIn(1500);
    });
}
```

Comment: You were 6 sec before me... :D

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

1. Use `onsubmit` on your `<form>` to catch submissions from the button and the enter key.
2. Prevent the form from submitting by returning `false`.
3. Submit the form after the fading is complete.

JS:

```
function xSubmit(formOBJ){
    $('#login').fadeOut(800);
    $('#logo').fadeIn(1500,function() {formOBJ.submit();});
    return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return xSubmit(this);">

<input type="submit" value="Login" />
```

Below is an example.
The form does not submit correctly on jsfiddle, but you get the idea.
http://jsfiddle.net/tYHs5/

Comment: @user2457241 Please try to be more clear about the exact problems you're having in your question next time.